# Android - Keyboard pop ups behind AlertDialog

Tags: android, listview, keyboard, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have an android application. My app has an alertDialog containing a listview.

When i click the editText that is located in listview,  keyboard pop ups behind the alertdialog so it is not reachable.

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

[image]

I call this function to call AlertDialog :

```
private void DProcedure(ApprovalOperationInput approvalOperationData, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((LayoutInflater) myContext.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService));
        View rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ApproveListview , null, false);


        ListView lst= ( ListView ) rootView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.list); 
        lst.ItemsCanFocus = true;
        List<ApprovalOperation> data = new List<ApprovalOperation> ();
        data = SetData ();
        approvalOperationAdapter = new ApprovalOperationAdapter (context, data.AsEnumerable ());
        lst.Adapter = approvalOperationAdapter;


        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.SetIconAttribute(Android.Resource.Attribute.AlertDialogIcon);
        builder.SetTitle(Resource.String.list_dialog_title);
        builder.SetView (rootView);

        builder.SetPositiveButton(Resource.String.dialog_ok, OkClicked);
        builder.SetNegativeButton(Resource.String.dialog_cancel, CancelClicked);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.Create ();

        alertDialog.Window.ClearFlags (WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable);
        alertDialog.Window.ClearFlags (WindowManagerFlags.AltFocusableIm);  
        alertDialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode (SoftInput.StateVisible);


        alertDialog.ShowEvent  += delegate {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            imm.ToggleSoftInput (ShowFlags.Forced, 0);
        };


        alertDialog.Show (); 
        alertDialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode (SoftInput.StateVisible); 
    }
```

ApprovalOperationAdapter's GetView method :

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {  
        MyViewHolder holder = null;
        var view = convertView;
        if (view != null) 
            holder = view.Tag as MyViewHolder;
        if (holder == null) {
            holder = new MyViewHolder ();
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.ApproveRow, null);
            holder.text1 = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.example_row_iv_image);
            holder.text2 = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.example_row_tv_title);
            holder.text3 = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.tvdesc);
            holder.text4 = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.tvdesc1);
            holder.text5 = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.tvdesc2);

            holder.text5.Click += delegate {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                imm.ToggleSoftInput (ShowFlags.Forced, 0);
            }; 
            view.Tag = holder;
        } 

        holder.text1.Text = data [position].ApprovalOperationDescription;
        holder.text2.Text = data [position].ApprovalOperationLongCode;
        holder.text3.Text = data [position].ApprovalOperationControlledEve;
        holder.text4.Text = data [position].ApprovalOperationApprovalNumer;  
        return view; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem :
I have added this code where i created and showed the dialog :

```
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.Create ();

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        imm.ToggleSoftInput (ShowFlags.Forced, 0); 

        alertDialog.Show (); 

        alertDialog.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable);
        alertDialog.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.AltFocusableIm);
        alertDialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode (SoftInput.StateVisible);
```